# Setting selected values for extjs tagfield

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm not too familiar with ExtJS nor the components and properties each component has, there were also a few examples that can be found.

I currently using ExtJS tagfield component like so, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmvg1bL2/22/):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['text'],
        data: []
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 500,
        height: 400,

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'tagfield',
                expand: Ext.emptyFn,
                forceSelection: false,
                store: store,
                createNewOnBlur: true,
                createNewOnEnter: true,
                hideTrigger: true
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

I was wondering what property I can use to set the default selected values of the tagfield, additionally, `createNewOnEnter` doesn't seem to work in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to set the `value` property directly on the `tagfield` component:

```js
{
    xtype: 'tagfield',
    value: ['foo', 'bar']
    // ...
}
```

To get this working in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmvg1bL2/23/) though I had to up the framework version from **5.0.0** to **5.1.0** - I'm guessing this was a bug but if you are not in a position to update your own project you will have to obtain a reference to the field and call [`setValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#method-setValue) manually.

Comment: Also `createNewOnEnter` is working fine in both your original and my updated fiddle - I'm not sure what you were expecting the behaviour to be.